# Xubuntu 17.04 Different keyboard layout for each window

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, keyboard-layout

Just today I installed Xubuntu 17.04 and I can't, for the life of me, figure out where I can enable the "Different layout for each window" setting. I came here from Gnome 3 where there is the gnome-tweak-tool which makes setting this option quite easy. Is there something of the sort for XFCE? 
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On XFCE, you have to add the **Keyboard layouts** plugin to a panel.  On Xubuntu it is installed by default.  If it's not, install it using: `apt-get install xfce4-xkb-plugin` and add it to a panel.

Right-click on it afterwards, and go to *Properties* to configure what you want.

Comment: Ooh jeez. I can't understand why this is "hidden". At any rate, thank you very much